# Magento 2.1.1 cannot add new role

Tags: magento-2.1

[image][While adding new user role the page is coming blank. Could anyone suggest any solution?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYKNJ.png)

Comment: what modifications did you make? please clear the cache. take a look at the logs

Comment: Can you share the logs from your developer console (chrome) and the logs in MAGENTO_ROOT/var/logs and MAGENTO_ROOT/var/reports?

Comment: I have refreshed the cache..but still no improvement.

Comment: I havent wroked before in this user role module. Its the first time I opened it, and facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this article, may help you 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7146